# Does Tomura have other powers aside decay?

Tags: my-hero-academia

Does Tomura have other powers aside decay? I mean, it doesnt make sense that he can be a powerful villain if the only power he has is decay. How could he face people who fire things from a large range, people who moves faster than a normal person, he wouldnt able to make them any damage if he can't touch them. Is he supposed to be faster than normal or something? How about resistance to attacks, does he have the resistance of a common person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tomura- Wikia](http://bokunoheroacademia.wikia.com/wiki/Tomura_Shigaraki)

Tomura is indeed a powerful villain, and there is a reason why he is the leader of League of Villains.

**Keen Intellect:** 
Tomura possesses a sharp mind and is analytical, being able to quickly realize Eraserhead's weaknesses in combat and taking advantage of them. He is able to deduce the workings of his opponents' abilities simply by observing them in action.

**Enhanced Strength:** 
Tomura seems to be stronger than his build suggests, as he was capable of holding Izuku by choking him with only four fingers. While doing so Izuku displays visible difficulty in trying to fight back.

**Enhanced Durability:** 
Tomura was able to take a point-blank blast of Katsuki's Quirk, sustaining little to no damage.

**Enhanced Speed:** 
Tomura appears to be able to move very quickly, as he was able to appear before Asui in an instant. He was even able to see Izuku after the latter had jumped at a speed that rivaled All Might's speed, and even reacted to it by immediately moving his hand to Kurogiri to warp the hand to reach for Izuku before Izuku's attack could make contact.